# How to determine if there is an object lying on the Plane at particular coordinates?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am implementing A* algorithm in 3D environment and I have came to a point where I need to determine whether there is something lying on a plane (on which my characters will be walking) at particular coordinates.

I have created a class `Board` which holds the map of of `Nodes` (each holds center of its coordinates). So we can say I have discretized the Plane to something similar like a chessborad. Now I need to know whether there is something on each `Node` to create a walkable/unwalkable map on this plane.

How can I do this in Unity3D ? Raycasting ?

**EDIT**

There is one thing that I can think of but I think it's a bit inefficient :

Create a temporary collider ( take area of `Board`'s tile and some height ) and check whether there is something colliding with it and then keep translating it for every tile in the `Board`.

Do you think this would be a good way  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Ghopper21](https://stackoverflow.com/users/848235/ghopper21)'s answer I came up with ShpereCasting each `Node` from above it e.g. `Node (0,0,0)` would be Spherecasted from `(0,100,0)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a raycast ([Physics.Raycast](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)) from each node coordinate. Make sure objects you are checking for have colliders. This will only check for a single point, however, not for the entire area of the node.

To check for an area, not just a point, above each node, you can use a sphere or capsule cast or check. See the choices in the list of class functions for [Physics](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics.html).

Another approach is to have a game object with an appropriately shaped trigger collider on each node in your scene. You could keep track of how many other objects (with colliders) are on each node by incrementing and decrementing a counter in the [OnTriggerEnter](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html) and [OnTriggerExit](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerExit.html) methods of a script (i.e. a MonoBehaviour subclass).